# Django not able to create object in python

Tags: python, arrays, django, python-3.x, django-views

I'm trying to create json but not able to create proper.my response is not similar that i want . please help to make it solve.

**views.py**

```
        json={}
        all_results=[]
        restaurants={}
        for i in restaurant:
            restaurant=Restaurant.objects.get(id=i.id)

            restaurant_serializer=RestaurantSerializers(restaurant)
            json['distace'] = i.distance 
            json['review_count']=reviews
            json['liked']=False

            restaurants['nearby_restaurants']=json
            restaurants['popular_restaurants']=json
            all_results.append(restaurants)
        return all_results
```

**response:**   that i'm getting

```
[
        {
            "top_reviewed_restaurants": {
                "distace": 1.53590595706412,
                 "review_count": 0,
                "liked": false
            },
            "nearby_restaurants": {
                "distace": 1.53590595706412,
                "review_count": 0,
                "liked": false

            }

        }
]
```

**Response:** that i want

```
{
  "nearby_restaurants": [
    {
     "distace": 1.53590595706412,
     "review_count": 0,
     "liked": false
    }
  ],
  "popular_restaurants": [
    {
      "distace": 1.53590595706412,
      "review_count": 0,
      "liked": false
    }
  ]

}
```

I'm trying to create json but not able to create proper.my response is not similar that i want . please help to make it solve.

Comment: Are you trying to generate some aggregated data? 
Please share there restaurant model and the response data you need.

Comment: "for i in restaurant:  restaurant=Restaurant.objects.get(id=i.id)" => this will certainly not work as you might expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    json={}
    all_results={}
    restaurants=[]
    for i in restaurant:
        restaurant=Restaurant.objects.get(id=i.id)

        restaurant_serializer=RestaurantSerializers(restaurant)
        json['distace'] = i.distance 
        json['review_count']=reviews
        json['liked']=False

        restaurants.append(json)
        all_results['nearby_restaurants']=restaurants
        all_results['popular_restaurants']=restaurants
    return all_results
```

your code snipe return `all_results` which is a list,so what you get is list rather than a dict. so you can redefine `all_results` to dict and change some code.
I dont test in my script, but you can try it.

last, you maybe try to user pdb to debug you code.here is one good post about pdb
[python-debugging-pdb](https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb/)

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want a dictionary but you're getting an array.

To get what you want, you should have:

```
all_results={
    'nearby_restaurants': [],
    'popular_restaurants': []
}

(...)

all_results['nearby_restaurants'].append(json)
all_results['popular_restaurants'].append(json)
```

This is considering your json variable contains the value of:

```
{
 "distace": 1.53590595706412,
 "review_count": 0,
 "liked": false
}
```

Comment: where is your reviews variable coming from then?

Comment: No my issue is to manage array it is like  array[1]0{2}nearby_restaurants{3}
and i want it  object{4}nearby_restaurants[1]

Comment: i updated my answer.. pls check if this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
our=[{
   "popular_restaurants":{"distace": 1.53590595706412,"review_count": 0,"liked": False},
    "nearby_restaurants": {"distace": 1.53590595706412,"review_count": 0,"liked": False}
}]

desired={
         "nearby_restaurants": [{"distace": 1.53590595706412,"review_count": 0,"liked": False}],
        "popular_restaurants": [{"distace": 1.53590595706412,"review_count": 0,"liked": False}]
   }


new_dict={}
new_json= (our[0])

nearby=[]
pop=[]

nearby.append((new_json['nearby_restaurants']))
pop.append((new_json['popular_restaurants']))


new_dict['popular_restaurants']=pop
new_dict['nearby_restaurants']=nearby
print (new_dict)
```